# Loading images for iPod, iPad, iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4

Tags: xcode, ios

After readying through the HIG, I see that it is best (and recommended) to produce both regular and high quality images.  My question is this: what is the standard practice for loading these images per device?

Do I check at start up for the device type and then do some sort of switch statement when I load images dynamically?  Thanks in advance.

Geo...

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question right, then there are different ways to load and blit images to the screen. You can use OpenGL ES which I am told would be the fastest way to load/blit images. You could use Quartz, which I am told would work but would be a pain to do (with all the coding). Alternatively you can use the normal User Interface framework to load and blit them, which would be the easiest I assume. OpenGL ES would take a while to learn and is mostly for 3D programming, and Quartz would also take a little while to learn, although maybe not as much as the OpenGL ES would take to learn though. The UI framework would be real easy to learn I think, and if you go through the apple iOS documentation, you can read up on OpenGL ES, Quartz, and the UI framework as well. Just google "apple dev", and it should be the first thing that pops up. Good luck.

Comment: No, I am talking about loading the images per device.  Not how to load them, but when to know which image to load.